# Multilanguage applications with MFC - workflow?

Tags: c++, mfc, multilingual

We have an English-only Windows C++ application based on MFC. It is still being developed, with updates being periodically sent to customers.

We now have a reseller who wants the ability to translate our application into other languages as needed. I understand the standard way of translating MFC applications is by using language-specific resource DLLs.

However, this presents a problem with updating the application. When updating the functionality, we sometimes add/change/delete GUI elements and text messages. How do we "push" these changes to people who would translate the resource DLL without them having to translate the whole DLL every time? What is the best workflow for this? Are there any tools that make developing and MAINTAINING multilanguage applications easier?

Are there any frameworks that could help? The reseller would prefer to have a simple text file with all text strings in it, so dealing with a resource DLL is already an unwanted compromise for them.

Are there any good books/articles on managing multilanguage application development/maintenance?

I never worked in a multilanguage project, so I am not sure what to look for. Thanks for any suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

Surely, you would keep your content, no matter how it is eventually deployed, in a source code control system.  So you can see the adds, changes, and deletes.

Only send the translater the changes that need to be translated.  Then they send the translations back to you.  Then you package the translation into a deployable object (e.g. DLL).

Comment: Sometimes proper translation depends on context. That's going to be difficult if they only get the diffs.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any tools that make developing and MAINTAINING multilanguage
>   applications easier?

Our product utilizes a large contingent of worldwide resellers, so, the product is typically translated into many languages.  We do not translate the resources directly.  We have established a relationship with each reseller.  Those that want to translate are given an English dll and a list of what has changed from release to release.  Most use a tool called [VisualLocalize](http://www.visual-localize.de/index.php?id=1&L=1) to localize the resources.  The tool produces a localized resource dll from our English dll.  That dll is then returned to us, or, packaged separately.  They use this type of tool because it allows them to not only localize strings, but, also resize dialog controls if needed.  Control size can be an issue depending on the language translation.  For example, the size of a text string may be large enough to hold an English word, but, too small for some translated languages.  While it may seem “dangerous” allowing a translator to change control sizes, we’ve had enough requests to do this that it’s now standard practice.  And, if memory serves me, this particular tool can import and export other files types which would potentially be of use in your particular case.